# How do I end the loop when the game is won?

Tags: python

After making functions for how to check if guesses are right or not, I am having difficulty with getting it to say what I want.

```
ntries = 0
while ntries < 10:
    ntries +=1
    if test_guess(code,guess)==True:
        print 'You win! You guessed the code in',ntries,'tries.'
    elif test_guess(code,guess)==False:
        guess = str(raw_input('Your guess: '))
print 'You lose!'
```

The problem is that when the player successfully guesses the code in, say, 8 tries, the result being printed is:

```
> You win! You guessed the code in 8 tries. 
> You win! You guessed the code in 9 tries. 
> You win! You guessed the code in 10 tries.
> You lose!
```

I realize it's because the while loop indicates that the loop keeps running when ntries is still less than 10. How do I have it so that it will only print the number of tries when won and stops there?

Comment: use `break` below the print statement.

Answer (score 5):

Break out of your loop with the `break` keyword inside of your `if` statement.

As an aside:  your `if-elif` block is overly verbose.  Since `test_guess` is returning something to be truthy, you could rewrite it as such.  This also moves the `ntries` variable inside of the else condition, since it only makes sense to increment it if you actually guessed, but failed.

```
if test_guess(code, guess):
    print 'You win!  You guess the code in', ntries, 'tries.'
    break
else:
    ntries += 1
    guess = str(raw_input('Your guess: '))
```

Answer (score 2):

just use break

```
ntries = 0
    while ntries < 10:
    ntries +=1
    if test_guess(code,guess)==True:
        print 'You win! You guessed the code in',ntries,'tries.'
        break
    elif test_guess(code,guess)==False:
        guess = str(raw_input('Your guess: '))
print 'You lose!'
```